# HTML canvas being resized to 0px

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, canvas

I have an MVC Razor page with a `<canvas>` element on it. Here is the view code

```
<canvas id="chartBlock@(id)" class="chart" height="@(Model.height ?? 500)" 
width="@(Model.width ?? 500)" style="min-width: @(Model.width ?? 0)px; 
min-height: @(Model.height ?? 0)px"></canvas>
```

It doesn't produce any output in Chrome or IE. Where the canvas should be is a blank square. When I inspect the element in Chrome, it shows this:

```
<canvas id="chartBlock30" class="chart" height="120" width="0" style="min-width: 220px;
 min-height: 120px; width: 0px; height: 120px;"></canvas>
```

If I mouse over it in the Chrome console, it highlights a block on the screen of the desired size.

[image: picture]

However, the width is 0 in the source and, when I try drawing to the canvas with javascript, context.canvas.width is equal to 0. Why is the width of the canvas 0?

Comment: Are your height and width properties nullable types? You can only use the null coalescing operator on reference or nullable types. Make sure you're using something like int? and not int

Comment: @heymega They are both nullable (int?) and being set explicitly to a constant value. Height = 120 and width = 220. Which is the size of the highlighted rectangle in the screen above.

Comment: OK - I was just taking a gamble tbh. If you hard code the width property (remove the razor code) do you still get this issue?

Comment: You could even check the response body from that XHR request that supplied your view to see if the canvas width has a value, just in case a script might be changing it

Comment: @heymega Yep, problem persists if I hardcode, in the view, height and width values. When I inspect the element and highlight the block, it has adjusted to the new size but the width still says 0 and I still get `context.canvas.width == 0` in my javascript.

Comment: This is definitely strange behaviour. The only time I would expect to get zero as the width is when the canvas is hidden. The only think I can suggest is to give us more of your code, that way I can mock up the issue and try to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<canvas id="chartBlock30" class="chart" height="120" width="220" style="width: 0; height: 0; border: 1px solid;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Canvas width and height not the same as style width and height and
why you need min-width and min-height?

Comment: I added min-width and min-height in an effort to mitigate this problem. I can't hardcode the values into the view because I use this view for many things. I can only hardcode them in the controller method.

Comment: answer is:: no matter what canvas size is, if you set style width:(x)px and height:(y)px, browser will display this block;
maybe you need to learn CSS first.

Comment: @sirdank This answer is correct - I didn't realise you were setting the width value in the inline style. I thought you were just setting the min-width.

Comment: @heymega I'm not setting width or height, that's just sugar that chrome adds in. If you look at the code in my question, you will see that I do not set width or height. That is only a symptom of the problem.

Comment: @heymega That is to say, if you look at other elements that are functioning properly, chrome adds width and height styling to them as well.

Comment: Ooh I thought so! Can you provide more code. I've tried mocking this up in a jsfiddle but i cant reproduce :(

Comment: @heymega It's a large application and I don't know what I'm allowed to post. This canvas is inside of a jquery accordion control but I have a fiddle of that working fine. If there's nothing obvious I'm missing, I'm going to resort to stepping through the javascript I suppose.